# Dns hostname debian etch guest not working vmware server 1.x

Tags: networking, vmware-server, virtualization, debian, debian-etch

I am running Etch on vmware server 1x on windows, I can only access the guest via ip and not hostname, I have no trouble with Debian Lenny, both installed 1 after each other with autp network config via local dhcp server, virtual network card is in bridged network mode, any ideas as to what may be the problem? im on a larger company lan which has either windows 2003 or bind server, not too sure which one is used as they both perform different functions...

Comment: You don't mention at all what you're using for DNS...I'm thinking this might get moved to superuser.

Comment: i think it has something to do with dhcp lease and leaving a hostname with the lease record or something..

Comment: i have tried setting "send host-name <hostname>" in the dhclient.conf but it didn't make any differrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing SAMBA and disabling WINS in smb.conf automagically made it work...